# Check if there are any running processes in the current tab of terminal

Tags: shell, applescript

I have a script that opens up as many terminal tabs as are devices plugged in, then it runs tests on those devices.  I would like to clean up all the terminal tabs after my tests are done.  I run some things in the background, and I don't know when each process will be done.

How can I check if there are process running in the current tab of terminal?

I plan to do a Command W in AppleScript to kill each terminal command after each tab of terminal has no running processes.

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Check out Terminal.app's Preferences. May be you can create a profile that behaves the way you like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use AppleScript, you can check the busy property:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    repeat with t in tabs of windows
        if busy of t is false then
            do script "exit" in t
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

`exit` closes a tab if you set "Preferences > Settings > Shell > When the shell exits" to "Close the window".

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution would be to take each command that you're running in a terminal and append "; exit" (Without the quotes) to it.

For example, if one of your commands was "ls", you would change it to "ls; exit".

Unfortunately, this doesn't work if you want to leave the terminal windows up to see results of what's being displayed. That can be solved by outputting the results of the first commands to some file, though.

Again using the example of ls, you could run "ls >> testfile.txt; exit" to output the results of ls to a file, and then have the terminal window close after it finishes executing.

Comment: ... well you said append "; exit" to the end of my command.  And when I did that, my tab didn't close after that command was finished running...

Comment: If it's displaying [Process finished] or something similar in the tab, then all you need to do is change a terminal setting so that the terminal window closes when the shell exits. Otherwise, you'd need to describe the problem a bit better for me to know how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry bro, it's just not working for me.  Thanks for the help, but I've used a different solution.  And I'm sure it's my fault that your solution didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "jobs" to check if there are any processes running in the background.